# Exporting Foreign Key Definitions as DDL Statements from MS Access

Tags: ms-access, version-control, ddl

I am trying to implement source control for my MS Access project (using git). The question, [How do you use version control with Access development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187506/how-do-you-use-version-control-with-access-development), helped me setup exporting/re-loading from text for queries, modules, forms, macros and reports. For the table schema, I attempted to export create statements using the code from this other question, [Table Creation DDL from Microsoft Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172895/table-creation-ddl-from-microsoft-access). I was then able to load tables back into Access using these create statements. Unfortunately, foreign key definitions are not exported. Is there a way to export the foreign key references as DDL statements?

Comment: There are some notes here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/698839/how-to-extract-the-schema-of-an-access-mdb-database/699516#699516

Comment: Crossposting [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/698839/how-to-extract-the-schema-of-an-access-mdb-database/9910716#9910716)

Answer (score 0):

I use [OASIS](http://oasis.dev2dev.de) for this purpose. Although this is originally designed to work with Subversion (TortoiseSVN), ignoring the SVN part makes this tool very helpful for Mercurial as well, so why not Git, too? It's not free, but it's worth the (small) price.

In short words, OASIS exports and imports every Access object to and from files (one file per object), avoiding the partially crazy implementation of MSSCCI ("tables and other objects"). Having those files, you may use any version control system you want.