# How to get a DDL statement from a DB in ACCESS

Tags: database

I'm doing a project for my DBA class and I've been asked to include the DDL from the database. I've already created the DB Tables and filled them. I tried to recreate the database with only the Tables without the columns filled in, but I cannot find where to get the DDL from. I am not creating this DDL from scratch (I don't know SQL that well). This is supposed to be done completely in Access, but I can't figure out where to get this statement, as there is no SQL view unless you're in Query Design mode. I've looked high and low on Google and I'm beginning to think that there is no way to get the DDL from Access.

Comment: Short answer is no, MSAccess doesn't do this really. Long answer is maybe you can find or build some tools to help with the task (if it is only a handful of tables you may want to just write it though - it will be good for you! Also see here: [table-creation-ddl-from-microsoft-access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172895/table-creation-ddl-from-microsoft-access)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm just confused because we didn't really cover writing SQL in this class, very briefly. Yet she expects an SQL statement. Thanks for pointing me in a good direction for writing it. It's only 5 tables.